# During deploy a k8s deployment, is it possible to spin-up only one replica at a time?

Tags: kubernetes

We want to make it so that even there are multiple replicas of a deployment, k8s only spin up one replcia, waiting for it to be scheduled and alive and then spin the next.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is called [Deployment Strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy)

The default is `RollingUpdate` with 25% for `maxUnavailable` and `maxSurge`, as you didn't specify what your needs, it's hard to suggest anything.

Comment: I don’t think this is going to work as it only affect when we update the deployment not when the deployment is first time rollout

Answer (score 0):

You can define this in the `Deployment` manifest, using:

```
strategy:
   type: RollingUpdate
   rollingUpdate:
     maxUnavailable: 1
     maxSurge: 1
```

Comment: I don’t think this is going to work as it only affect when we update the deployment not when the deployment is first time rollout